# Importing facebook sdk for android in mac

Tags: android, facebook, macos, sdk

I want to import Facebook sdk for android into my project and would like to use properties like Facebook:preset_size. I would also like to run the samples. I am doing this in mac.

All the examples that I have seen are for windows. Facebook sdk doesn't download as a zip in mac. Also when i try to set the source directory of the module as the folder that is downloaded or the Facebook folder inside it, I get an error that says "Specify location of the gradle or Android Eclipse project".

I have already compiled Facebook sdk using gradle and have successfully implemented Facebook login. But I want to run the samples and see the code.

Can anyone help me in doing this in mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for not being able to use the preset_size attribute in xml.
I am doing it through code now -

profilePictureView.setPresetSize(ProfilePictureView.LARGE);

As for running the samples,

I downloaded the github repository facebook-sdk-master and then imported it into my project. Then I changed the application name of the samples and set their app_id to my app_id. Now I am able to run them.